# javascript multiple loops

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to get the sum of a list of words displayed in an HTML browser.

If each word is assigned a number i.e

> a is 1,
>   b is 2

and so on upto z is 26, then the sum of apple should be 50. I want them to be displayed in browser like below:

```
apple  
carrot
money  

50
75
72
```

but I am not able to get the loop to work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="script.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function newSquare(){
      for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
         calcAlpha(j);
      }
   }
   function newDisplay(){
      for(var k=0; k<10; k++){
         calcAlpha(k);
      }
   }
   function calcAlpha() {
      var word = document.getElementById("square + j").childNodes[0].data;
      var sum = 0;
      for(var i=word.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
         sum += (word.charCodeAt(i) - 96);
      }
      document.getElementById("display + k").innerHTML=sum
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Calculate sum of words</h1>
   <table>
      <tr><td id="square1">apple</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square2">carrot</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square3">money</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square4">game</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tr><td id="display1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   </table>
   <div id="display"></div>
   <button onclick="calcAlpha()">calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone can sort this for me? I am still a beginner at Javascript, and I dont understand how to put i,j, and k in loops.
Thanks.

Comment: Your element ids should look like `document.getElementById("display" + k).innerHTML=sum` Close quotes and concatenate on the variable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about what these function should do, and what arguments they would have? Their names are not speaking, or don't match the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete answer:

There are three main problems with the code. First, i, j, and k are `var`'s with specific integer values in this example. `"square + j"` is just a string that does not have the desired  values (i.e. `square1`, `square2`, etc.). As Michael has suggested, you should put "square" + j.

The second issue is that the only function to run in your webpage is `calcAlpha()`, which you call in the `onclick` event of the `button` element. Within `calcaAlpha()` you never call `newSquare()` or `newDisplay()`, so they never execute.

The third issue is the namespace, or scope of your javascript variables. Within `calcAlpha()` you cannot access the variables `j` or `k` because they are declared in external functions that don't encapsulate the `calcAlpha()` function. However, you can access the variable `i` because it is declared in `calcAlpha()`.

The solution to your problem would be to remove `newDisplay()` and `newSquare()` and change `calcAlpha()` to something like this:

```
function calcAlpha() {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        var word = document.getElementById("square" + j).childNodes[0].data;
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=word.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            sum += (word.charCodeAt(i) - 96);
        }
        document.getElementById("display" + j).innerHTML=sum

    }
}
```

This is basically the combined code for `newSquare()` and `newDisplay()` which is put into `calcAlpha()` and fixed for the other issues described above. Notice that the variable `k` is unnecessary because you want to put the numeric sum of `squareN` into `displayN`, so you can use a single variable, `j`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with those functions, but try this:

```
function run() {
// reads, calculates and prints all words
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        var word = document.getElementById("square"+i).childNodes[0].data;
        var result = calcAlpha(word);
        document.getElementById("display"+i).childNodes[0].data = result;
    }
}
function calcAlpha(text) {
   text = text.toLowerCase();
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i=text.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
       sum += text.charCodeAt(i) - 96;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

And call the `run` function from the button.

Comment: im trying to create a list of sum of words, i study numerology.i wanted to combine the two...but my js sucks, it is an amazing language if one knows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I saw that you did incorrectly right away was getting the element by id. You were including the looping variable as a string instead of an int. Here is my solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">

   function calcAlpha()
   {
        for(j =1; j<=4; j++)
        {
            var word = document.getElementById("square" + j).innerHTML;
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i=word.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
            {
                sum += (word.charCodeAt(i) - 96);
            }
            document.getElementById("display" + j).innerHTML=sum
        }
   }

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Calculate sum of words</h1>
   <table>
      <tr><td id="square1">apple</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square2">carrot</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square3">money</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="square4">game</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tr><td id="display1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="display4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   </table>
   <div id="display"></div>
   <button onclick="calcAlpha()">calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually, `i` is the running variable of the outer loop and `j` for the inner.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, like Michael said, is this:

```
document.getElementById("square + j")
// and
document.getElementById("display + k")
```

This will look for the element whose `id` exactly matches `"square + j"` or `"display + k"`. To concatenate the value of a variable to a string, use `"square" + j` and `"display" + k`.

The second problem is that in the context of `calcAlpha`, the variables `j` and `k` are undefined. You can fix this by either making them accessible to `calcAlpha` (by defining them outside the scope of `function calcAlpha`) or by passing `j` (or `k`) as a parameter. You're already doing the first part of that (actually passing it along). All you need now is to use it in the declaration of `calcAlpha`, like so:

```
function calcAlpha(index) {
  var word = document.getElementById("square" + index).childNodes[0].data;
  // [...]
}
```

The variable `index` will now contain the value of the `j` or `k` you passed along.

One other thing: you're calling `calcAlpha` both from the other functions and from the `<button>`'s onclick. That's probably not what you want to do. Have a look at [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783169/990877), his/her solution should solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, have you test the solution you've described with the author's code?

Comment: @ted: I don't see why I should. My answer doesn't provide a copy-paste solution ([Bergi already did that very well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11783169/990877)), but rather I'm trying to help the OP to understand why her code doesn't work. I think that would be of value to her, even if it isn't "the" answer to "the" question.

Comment: yeah that's true, otherwise id have no clue of whats going on, but this index example is easy to understand.thanks PPvG